# Why I obtain an ERR_CACHE_MISS when I use the javascript:history.back() to come back to the previous page into this Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, browser-cache, back-button

I am experiencing a strange proble on a Spring MVC application.

I have a FreeMarker page (but this is not important that this is Freemarker) that contain a **javascript:history.back()** link to come back to the previous page.

This is my page code:

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />

<#include "../layout/header.ftl">

    <div class="container page-content">
        <h2>Registrati ai servizi</h2>
        <!-- steps indicator -->
        <!-- inserire sempre classe "last" su ultimo elemento -->
        <!-- classi valide: "active" su elemento attivo e "done" su elementi precedenti ad "active" -->
        <ul id="progress" class="clearfix">
            <li class="step1 done">
                <p><span>Passaggio</span> 1</p>
            </li>
            <li class="step2 done">
                <p><span>Passaggio</span> 2</p>
            </li>
            <li class="step3 active">
                <p><span>Passaggio</span> 3</p>
            </li>
            <li class="step4 last">
                <p><span>Passaggio</span> 4</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- steps indicator -->
        <div class="form-container summary">
            <h3>Riepilogo dati</h3>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Codice fiscale:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep1Form.codiceFiscale}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Nome:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.nome}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Cognome:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.cognome}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Data di nascita:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.dataNascita}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Nazione:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.codiceNazione?substring(3)}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Provincia:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.codiceProvincia?substring(4)}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Comune:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.codiceComune?substring(6)}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Sesso:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.sesso}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Email:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.email}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Termini e condizioni:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.condizioniGenerali?string("Acconsento", "Non acconsento")}</p>
            </div>
                <div class="data-show">
                <p class="data-text">Trattamento dei dati personali:</p>
                <p class="data-value">${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.informativaPrivacy?string("Acconsento", "Non acconsento")}</p>
            </div>
            <form id="reg-form" name="reg-form" action="<@spring.url '/registrazione/step4' />" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="codiceFiscale" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep1Form.codiceFiscale}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="nome" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.nome}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cognome" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.cognome}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.email}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dataNascita" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.dataNascita}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="nazione" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.codiceNazione}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="provincia" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.codiceProvincia}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="comune" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.codiceComune}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="sesso" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.sesso}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="condizioniGenerali" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.condizioniGenerali?c}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="informativaPrivacy" value="${iscrizioneStep3Form.iscrizioneStep2Form.informativaPrivacy?c}">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block submit-btn" aria-label="conferma i tuoi dati" tabindex="10">Conferma i tuoi dati</button>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <div class="footer-form">
                <a href="javascript:history.back()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span> Indietro</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<#include "../layout/footer.ftl">
```

As you can see at the end of the page there is this link used to come back to the previous page:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span> Indietro</a>
```

The problem is that clicking on this link I can't come back to the previous page but I obtain this **Chrome error** that in english sounds like (I am traslating from italian):

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This web page requires data that you entered earlier in order to be
>   properly displayed. You can resend the data, but in this case you will
>   repeat the previous action performed on the page.
>
> ERR_CACHE_MISS

Also FireFox give me a similar error message that say that the document is expired and that it is not yet into the FireFox cache.

This is the controller method that show the previous page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = STEP_3, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String iscrizioneStep3(@ModelAttribute IscrizioneStep3Form iscrizioneStep3Form, @ModelAttribute("registrazioneInfo")RegistrazioneInfo registrazioneInfo, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws APIException, ParseException {

    // Se ci sono errori di compilazione del form:
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        setErrorMessageInModel("Codice Fiscale errato", model);
        return FM_ERROR_PAGE;
    }

    if(registrazioneInfo.getCodiceFiscale().equals(null)) {
        setErrorMessageInModel("Si è verificato un errore nella compilazione del precedente step di registrazione", model);
        return FM_ERROR_PAGE;

    }

    model.addAttribute("iscrizioneStep3Form", iscrizioneStep3Form);
    return STEP_3;
}
```

What could be the problem? Why I obtain this error message? For other page it works fine